# Change button class on success ajax result

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap a button and span. When the button is clicked I call an ajax function if result is success I want to change button class, button text and span class. The classes is changing but not working correctly. When the class is changed the button size is increasing.

```
<button id="check" type="" class="btn btn-danger btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> Check</button>

        $("#check").click(function(){
        var lat = $('#lat').val();
        var lng = $('#lng').val();  
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'kds_populate_db2.php?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng,
                data: {
                    lat:lat,
                    lng:lng
                },
                async: true,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {                       
                    $("#check").addClass('btn btn-success btn-block').removeClass('btn btn-danger btn-block');
                    $('#check>span').removeClass('glyphicon glyphicon-remove').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-ok');
                    $("#check").val("checked");

                }
            });         
    });
```

Comment: Since the issue involves presentation components you probably want to include the css

Comment: Why are you adding and removing the same classes to an element?

Comment: I change the button color and the span icon. Firstly the button color is red  When the result is success the button color will be green

Comment: P.S - I don't see a problem.  See this [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/m3L2twto/).

Comment: @Hermes - but you are adding the class `btn` and then immediately removing it.  That doesn't make sense.  Same  thing with `btn-block`

Comment: I when click the button that will be minimized button

Comment: @Hermes - then just remove the class.  Don't add it.

Comment: I tried I get same error. The button will be minimized and text doesnt change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
$("#check").addClass('btn btn-success btn-block').removeClass('btn btn-danger btn-block');
```

invert remove and add class:

$("#check").removeClass('btn btn-danger btn-block').addClass('btn btn-success btn-block');

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#chengeIt').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#check").removeClass('btn btn-danger btn-block').addClass('btn btn-success btn-block')[0].childNodes[1].textContent = 'Success';
    $('#check>span').removeClass('glyphicon-check').addClass('glyphicon-ok-sign');
    $("#check").val("checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button id="check" type="" class="btn btn-danger btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-check" aria-hidden="true"></span> Check</button>
<button id="chengeIt" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
```

Comment: You are right class is changed but button text doesnt change

Comment: @Hermes Now the button text changes to "success".

Comment: You are perfect really thank you so much it take my so much time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if you have a problem with the size, maybe you have another css who conflict with your button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function(){
    $("input").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      
      $.ajax({
        // change complete for success
        complete: function(){
          $("input").removeClass("btn-primary");
          $("input").addClass("btn-danger");
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
input{
  outline: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="click me!">
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working but the button text doest change